# Maven-plugin @Component injection of third party plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am developing a custom plugin for Maven project which requires additional info from 'other plugins'; for example the `maven-compiler-plugin`.

**Is it possible to inject external plugins components into mine?**
I would like to understand how the `@Component` injection by Maven works, because I cannot find any nice info about this and how its component container is filled when plugin execution starts.

I've started trying by `@Component` annotation, but when I run my custom plugin it returns the error which there are no elements/candidates for that field.
I tried with the following four cases:

1. `@Component private CompilerInfoMojo compiler`
2. `@Component private AbstractCompilerMojo compiler`
3. `@Component(role = CompilerInfoMojo.class) private AbstractCompilerMojo compiler`
4. `@Component(role = CompilerInfoMojo.class) private CompilerInfoMojo compiler`

Then I moved to inject the `MavenPluginManager`, but when I lookup for the CompilerMojo it cannot find it and the manager throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo@Component
```

Example of code:

```
@Mojo(name = "info")
public class InfoMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Component private MavenPluginManager mpm;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenSession session;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${mojoExecution}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MojoExecution execution;

   public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    final Log log = getLog();

    log.info("Hello World!");

    final List<Plugin> build = project.getBuildPlugins();
    for (Plugin current : build) {
      log.info(current.getArtifactId());
    }

    try {
      final CompilerMojo comp = mpm.getConfiguredMojo(CompilerMojo.class, session, execution);
      log.info(String.valueOf(comp.getPluginContext()));
    } catch (PluginConfigurationException | PluginContainerException e) {
      log.error(e);
      throw new MojoExecutionException("Error", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Log shows the compiler plugin is available:

```
[INFO] Hello World!
[INFO] maven-compiler-plugin
[INFO] plexus-component-metadata
[INFO] maven-clean-plugin
[INFO] maven-resources-plugin
[INFO] maven-jar-plugin
[INFO] maven-plugin-plugin
[INFO] maven-surefire-plugin
[INFO] maven-install-plugin
[INFO] maven-deploy-plugin
[INFO] maven-site-plugin
```

The complete stack trace is the following:

```
[ERROR]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: Unable to load the mojo 'info' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'prv.sigur.levanzo.maven.plugins:info-maven-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:557)
   at prv.sigur.levanzo.maven.plugins.InfoMojo.execute (InfoMojo.java:74)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
     role: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo
 roleHint: prv.sigur.levanzo.maven.plugins:info-maven-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:info
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
   at prv.sigur.levanzo.maven.plugins.InfoMojo.execute (InfoMojo.java:74)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
   at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next (RealmFilteredBeans.java:118)
   at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next (RealmFilteredBeans.java:1)
   at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next (DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
   at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next (DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
   at prv.sigur.levanzo.maven.plugins.InfoMojo.execute (InfoMojo.java:74)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: Simple answer to this: No it's no possible to inject other plugins. The question is why do you need them?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need to analyse and extract some information about the POM configuration. In particular I need to know how some "plugins" are configured. For example, I need to get the java versions of the compiler configuration and I though that If I could get the "correct plugin instance mojo class" (like CompilerMojo) I could use its java fields/method/etc... instead of duplicating the logic for how to retrieve its configuration.
Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please give more detail what kind of plugin you are trying to implement... furthermore you can of course define a property like the maven compiler plugin does which is filled by defaults..

Comment: I want to generate a detail from the project effective pom about some "specfic info" which I decide. I would to know which java version is set as target, which test are enabled (surefire, failsafe, etc...), its dependencies (type, version, etc...), if specific plugins are inside and how they're configured (for example the sonar-scanner, but they're plugins that I choose to lookup).

Comment: If you like to get the information which tests are enabled ...than you need to reimplement the whole scanning/expression logic which the different testing frameworks (like JUNit, JUnit Jupiter, TestNG) will aready do... What purpose should that plugin fulfil ? The dependencies can be seen by reports ? I would suggest to take a deep look into the reportings like this: https://khmarbaise.github.io/maven-it-extension/dependency-management.html or give more details what you like to achieve and more important what the purpose of such things would be?

Comment: I need to construct an info model which is common through different projects. These projects could have different java version for compiling, disabled test phase, required static code analysis phase, etc... Thanks for the link, for sure I am going to take a look about that.

Comment: For static code analysis there existing already a number of tools (SonarQube for example) would mean create that on your own?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not interested to create one on my own, but I am looking for a way how to extract the plugin configuration which are present in the pom. In the example I would like to extract the which java compiler and which version of java are configured for the compiler plugin. Do you have any suggestion about this?

Comment: The problem is with which java compiler is one thing (which is related to the used JDK via JAVA_HOME) and the other one is source/target or release... technically you can extract the information via the MavenSession...but I would not recommend such things..

Comment: I feel MavenSession is covering every case where the plugin compiler has a 'configuration' section and the developer should 'duplicate' the property names/configuration to extract. I do not have good feelings on the default values of the configuration, for example if there's no "source" property/parameters the maven plugin compiler has a default value, but you cannot get from MavenSession. Am I wrong or I am missing anything? ... I cannot find any plugins which could describe "the plugin" to the current effective pom result

Comment: Yes you are right about defaults..because the defaults are defined by the plugin itself....